# How to present multiple controllers as popups using swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, popup

I've got an `UITableViewController` that is presented (as popover) from my `UIViewController` by  a `segue`. In the `UITableViewCell`, I have an image that I'm presenting as popover from my AppDelegate (because the function that is presenting image can be called everywhere in my app).

**My problem**: I can't present more than 1 controller at a the time, I'm forced to dismiss my current controller to display my image.

Here some code:

```
// Function that is displaying my image(s) in my AppDelegate
func showFullScreenImage(imageURL : String, imageArray : [String]) {
    if AppDelegate.DeviceType.IS_IPAD {
        let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard_iPad", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("fullScreenImageViewController") as! FullScreenImageViewController
        controller.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.window!.rootViewController!.view
        controller.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection()
        controller.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRectMake(self.window!.rootViewController!.view!.frame.width/2, self.window!.rootViewController!.view!.frame.height/2, 1, 1)
        controller.mImageArray = imageArray
        self.window!.rootViewController!.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        controller.loadImage(imageURL)
    }
}
```

That's what I'm doing to display my images:

```
func displayImageFromComment(imageUrl: String, listImage: [String]) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) {
        (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).showFullScreenImage(imageUrl, imageArray: listImage)
    }
}
```

If I don't dismiss, I get this error:

> Warning: Attempt to present MyApp.FullScreenImageViewController: 0x196530c0  on MyApp.RootViewController: 0x17e0f560 which is already presenting MyApp.BoardViewCommentsController: 0x181de000

After doing that, when I dismiss the controller that is displaying images, I'm back to the main `UIViewController`, NOT to my `UITableViewController`.

Comment: navigation controller can present only 1 controller at the time. You can instead of presenting use push another view controller, or create custom animation adding child view controller (addChildViewCOntroller) on your root controller

Comment: Thanks, i've finally used a modal segue in full screen. But thanks you to give me this solution. I think that it will helps me in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **finally** use a `modal segue` from my `UITableViewController` to my controller that is displaying my images.

And it works fine.